# OCL-based model transformation languages

Tags: ocl, epsilon

Which of the model transformation languages are ocl-based?
Is Epsilon Transformation Language (ETL) ocl-based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most transformation languages like ATL, QVT and ETL are OCL-based, specially when it comes to define the pattern-matching part of the transformation

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know reference that write ETL is ocl-based model transformation? I read in `The Epsilon Transformation Language` article EOL is ocl-based model transformation language and ETL used EOL, but I don't find an statement that explicitly said ETL is ocl-based.

Comment: EOL itself has a significant OCL influence so by transtivity ETL as well

Answer (score 1):

QVT is strongly OCL-based; the OMG specification specifies that all three QVT languages extend OCL. Similarly Acceleo follows the MOFM2T specification which extends OCL.

ATL is strongly influenced by OCL, but takes a few liberties through lack of support for shorthands, type inference and indeed strong typing.

EOL and so ETL is influenced by OCL. EOL makes some deliberate deviations such as eliminating the power/confusion of "."/"->".

Xtend/Xbase and OCL share the same functional programming influences and so some aspects of Xtend can seem familiar to OCL users.